# Structuring helper functions

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an abstraction above a couple very similar, but different interfaces and can't decide on the best way to structure my code to keep is as DRY as possible. So I'm trying to refactor out all the similar code into their own functions, but aren't sure where to place these functions.

Current setup:

```
var module = function module( API ) {
    var properties,
        doSomething = function doSomething( config ) {
            if (A) {
                foo();
            }
            else if (B) {
                // lotsa bar1 code
            }
            else if (C) {
                // lotsa bar2 code
            }
            else {
                error();
            }
        };
    return {
        // public interface
    };
};
```

I would like to fold the bar1 and bar2 code into its own function, but can't decide where to place this function. I don't really want to cause overhead by declaring the helper inside the function it's helping, although it's the most readable option.

Option A: Make the helper function another direct method of the module.
This seems to be the easiest approach, but I don't like 'polluting' my main module namespace with functions 
"that don't represent a method of the module."
edit: "that don't represent an action of the module."

```
var module = function module( API ) {
    var properties,
        bar = function bar() {
            // help doSomething
        },
        doSomething = function doSomething( config ) {
            if (A) {
                foo();
            }
            else if (B) {
                bar(B);
            }
            else if (C) {
                bar(C);
            }
            else {
                error();
            }
        };
    return {
        // public interface
    };
};
```

Option B: Create a seperate namespace for all the helpers. This is how I usually structure these kinds of extra functions, but the more I use this version, the less satisfying it seems.

```
var module = function module( API ) {
    var properties,
        helpers = {
           'bar' : function bar( input ) {
                // help doSomething
            }
        },
        doSomething = function doSomething( config ) {
            if (A) {
                foo();
            }
            else if (B) {
                helpers.bar(B);
            }
            else if (C) {
                helpers.bar(C);
            }
            else {
                error();
            }
        };
    return {
        // public interface
    };
};
```

Option C: Set the helper function as a method of the main function.

```
var module = function module( API ) {
    var properties,
        doSomething = function doSomething( config ) {
            if (A) {
                foo();
            }
            else if (B) {
                doSomething.bar(B);
            }
            else if (C) {
                doSomething.bar(C);
            }
            else {
                error();
            }
        };
    doSomething.bar = function( input ) {
         // help doSomething
    };
    return {
        // public interface
    };
};
```

And option D would be to create a closure around the function.

Maybe I'm putting way too much thought in this and it's all a matter of preference.

Comment: You said: "I don't like 'polluting' my main module namespace with functions that don't represent a method of the module." This might be a philosophical question... but what do you consider to be a valid method of a module? I'm asking because if you simply declare `bar` just like `doSomething` (as you did in the second code block), `bar` _becomes_ a method of the module in my opinion. So why don't you want to do that - especially since you do seem to even have a public interface where you can make sure that `bar` stays "`private`" to the outside world?

Comment: Personally, I use option `A`. Then, what I return is something like: `return { publicName: privateFunction };`

Comment: It's indeed a philosophical thing mostly. My reasoning is that every variable I declare in my module, the props signify state and the methods signify an action the module can do. The helper methods are neither state or action, since they only help a public or private action do its thing. I used to always use option A and make everything a method, but ended up putting comments like "// public action 'doSomething'" after each method and "// private helper for 'functionName'" after each helper method, so I started looking for other options.

Comment: @HaukeP., Shilly: You have an odd philosophy :-) To me, only what the module exports are methods of that module. Everything else doesn't really matter - it's local declarations in the module. If you want to structure your module code to make the difference more obvious, I'd recommend to define the public methods directly as properties of the exported object.

Comment: @Shilly: I don't see what overhead you are considering when declaring the helper function inside `doSomething`. It's the most readable option, as you say yourself, so go for it!

Comment: @Bergi: This specific module I'm making will use 'doSomething' to iterate over several large arrays, hence I was fearing that redeclaring the helper each time inside the function would be a noticable performance hit. I should probably use option A again for small modules together with a better function naming scheme like 'doSomething' and 'doSomething_helper' to make it more readable and option D for code that exports the entire module as public. Once I personally feel it's becoming unreadable again, the issue is probably that the module does too many things and should be split up. :)

Comment: @Shilly: Hardly noticeable. If you had to care that much for performance, you probably wouldn't use method calls at all :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I mostly use C++, Java, C# etc., i.e. languages that know  `private` methods. To me, `bar` in this example appears like a typical candidate for a private method. So I wouldn't follow your definition of a module method being a method that has to be publicly accessible in the end. Therefore I'd simply turn `bar` into such a private method and only export `doSomething` in the public interface.

Comment: @HaukeP.: To my knowledge, C++ or Java don't have a notion of modules, do they? Also, in Java there are only methods, so of course you'd call it "private method" what is simply a local function in JS :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, that's what I meant. If I understand things correctly, based on the given code it should be easy to make sure that `bar` in the second code block is not exported in any way: Simply don't put it into the object that `module(API)` returns. (I assumed that `doSomething` *will* be put into that return object though, i.e. it will be "exported"  or "made public" this way.) But based on your last comment I come to think that I have a different understanding on what Shilly and you denote with "module". That might be the source of my confusion. :)